# Angular2 excel file download via Spring boot

Tags: excel, spring, angular, spring-boot, download

I am trying to download excel file through connecting spring boot from angular2 . 
My boot looks like below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value="/downloadExcel/{weekEnd}",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity  downloadLastWeekOOOData(@PathVariable String weekEnd,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{


    File result=new File("C:\\sayan\\poi-test.xls");
    String type=result.toURL().openConnection().guessContentTypeFromName("poi-test.xls");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\sayan\\poi-test.xls"));
    byte[]out=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "poi-test.xlsx");
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type",type);

    ResponseEntity  respEntity = new ResponseEntity(out, responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
    System.out.println(respEntity.getBody());
    return respEntity;
```

}

angular2 code looks like :

```
downloadExcel(weekEnd: string) {
let downloadSuccess: boolean = false;
this.lastWeekOOOService.downloadExcel(weekEnd)
  .subscribe(blob => {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "Report.xlsx";
    link.click();
  },
  error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
  () => console.info("OK"));
```

}

service looks like :

```
downloadExcelOOO(weekEnd:string): Observable<Response> {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/downloadExcel/'+weekEnd)
                .map(res => new Blob([res],{ type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }))
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

But I am getting a file Report.xlsx downloaded which is corrupted .

Comment: try setting the contentType in your Angular code.

Comment: It is already set in service : 
    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

Comment: At first it is showing an alertbox saying "The file you are trying to open is in different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.Do you want to open it now ?" 
When yes is clicked , the xls file opens with a cell as :
Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://169.172.218.252:8080/downloadExcel/downloadExcelOOO/2017-11-05

Answer (score -1):

copy excel as inputstream to response outputstream in spring.
in angular put httpoptions in post and in httpoptions put param responseType:'arraybuffer' as 'arraybuffer'. in subscribe use object of arraybuffer in blob directly